# Passing "*()" as an argument to a program in bash

Tags: c, linux, bash

EDIT 2: even doing "ls *()" causes bash to not return and use 100% of one cpu. Does anyone know why bash is doing this?

I was learning C and learning about arguments and was wondering what characters do weird things when passed as arguments. I passed "*()" without quotes to a c program through bash like:

```
$ ./program *()
```

Bash could not be quit with ctrl c or ctrl z. When I looked at htop it was using 100% of one CPU and I had to SIGKILL it. Does anyone know what is going on here. I am just curious.

EDIT: even the simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ return 0; }
```

causes this behavior.

Comment: what program it was?

Comment: You should have gotten a syntax error from `bash` due to the unquoted parentheses.

Comment: @chepner `ls *()` doesn't do anything usefull on my system, but i don't get an error from bash about the parentheses

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: `ls *()` -> `ls: cannot access *(): No such file or directory`

Comment: What is your operating system and `bash` version? The unquoted parentheses should prevent `bash` from even running `program`, so it's unclear what your program is actually receiving as an argument, and what it does with that argument.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) Linux Mint

Comment: @Will: does it happen in any directory, or only in one particular directory?

Comment: @chepner: it's not a syntax error. It's an extended glob which matches the empty string (not particularly useful as a glob, but try `[[ "" = *() ]]`)

Comment: It's a syntax error if extended glob support isn't enabled with `shopt -s extglob`, but I didn't think to ask if that was the case. If it is, the pattern can't match anything, and so the program receives the literal string `*()` (unless `shopt -s nullglob` is used, in which case the program doesn't receive *any* arguments).

Comment: @rici this happens in any directory

Comment: You make it sound like it is your program that runs and consumes a full CPU. Isn't it bash that is running and consuming a full CPU?

Comment: @Cornstalks yes its bash, i tried to clarify that in edit 2 but i will make it more clear

Comment: @Will: I edited it to make it a little clearer. "The program" makes it sound like you're talking about your C program. I changed it to "Bash" because that's what you're talking about.

Comment: I think @rici's comment has the answer: if it's a glob that matches the empty string, it might be a runaway match that's doing far more matching than you think.

Comment: I cant reproduce this on bash 4.2.24, maybe its new and a bug?

Comment: I see similar behavior (Linux Mint 17, bash 4.3.11) typing `echo *()` at a shell prompt. I do have `extglob` and `globstar` enabled. The bash process didn't seem to consume a lot of CPU, but it did become non-responsive, and I had to kill it from another shell window.

Comment: @chepner: Debian's bash-completion scripts shopt -s extglob, so it's pretty common to see it set. (Always cool to hide a setting like that in a place you'd ever think to look for it.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: There was a bug in 4.2 where a bad multibyte sequence in a filename would put the glob matcher into an endless loop, but that would be directory dependent and anyway I think it was fixed before 4.3.11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in bash, fixed in version 4.3.16. It occurs only if the `extglob` feature is enabled, for example if you have a command like

```
shopt -s extglob
```

in your `.bashrc` or some other init file.

I can reproduce it consistently with bash 4.3.11 on Linux Mint 17:

```
$ bash --norc
bash-4.3$ mkdir empty
bash-4.3$ cd empty
bash-4.3$ echo *()
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash-4.3$ shopt -s extglob
bash-4.3$ echo *()
```

The shell hangs after the last command.  Note that I ran it in an empty directory; the problem also occurs in a non-empty directory.

The bash manual documents a form of wildcard that's enabled only when `extglob` is enabled:

```
`*(PATTERN-LIST)'
     Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns.
```

Given `*()`, that's zero or more occurrences of the empty string. Since there are infinitely many occurrences of the empty string in any string, I can see how that might cause an infinite loop if there's no special-case code to avoid it.

And it appears to have been fixed in a later version. I see the problem in 4.3.11 but not in 4.3.30. rici's comment suggests that patch 016 is likely to have fixed it. And the [bug report](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-04/msg00100.html) corresponding to the patch includes this:

```
1) bash gets stuck

shopt -s extglob
echo !(*/) # never returns, cannot be interrupted
```

which I'd say confirms that that's the bug.

Comment: My guess is that it was fixed by patch 016, which is the only patch I see between 011 and 030 which touches glob functions.

Comment: @rici: Yes, that's almost certainly it.

Answer (score 0):

You might see what it is doing with strace -p*pid*. Is the behavior reproducible after a reboot? Bash gave me a syntax error when I tried it on CentOs 6.3.  Seems to me that something is corrupted in your system but maybe only in the running kernel, perhaps in the proc table.

```
tn:11: cat program.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ return 0; }
tn:12: gcc program.c
tn:13: ./a.out *()
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
tn:13: bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)
tn:14: uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Oct 16 14:40:53 UTC
2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
tn:15: cat  /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
tn:16: gcc  --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
```

Comment: It's a known bash bug; see my answer.